# How to provider user with autocomplete suggestions for given boost::spirit grammar?

Tags: c++, parsing, autocomplete, boost-spirit

I am using Boost::Spirit to build simple "data-filter" language in my C++ GUI application for non-technical users. Language is very similiar to plain English and parse-able into AST. I am requested to make the process as user-friendly as possible, so I wish to provide CLang-like error messages ("Unrecognized 'tokken', did you meant 'token'?") and autocompletion.

The question in place is how to use Boost::Spirit grammar to generate possible token list for both goals (I will use simple string distance algorithm to satisfy first requirement)?

My ideas so far:

- Add position and length in source stream to token definition obtained from parser.
- Add special invalid token to grammar, which will match anything... well... not valid :-)
- If user presses ctrl + space, build AST (with invalid token the tree will be always buildable), then look for token inside current cursor position
- Use simple matcher on all possible tokens (I have token list after all) and prepare a list of suggestions

The problem with this solution is the suggestion will also suggest tokens that are invalid for given place. And if I add (and I will) definable identifiers, I have much bigger problem in hand...

One more constraint: I want to have grammar for this language defined in only one place; If the grammar changes, I want to autocompleter be aware of this changes after recompilation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I decided to try the concept.

Here's my attempt.

### Plan

Let's parse arithmetic expressions with function calls.

Now, we want to parse (partial) expression with possible unknown identifiers.

In case of incomplete expressions, we want to "imply" the minimal token to complete it (and potentially continue parsing).

In case of unknown identifiers, we want to fuzzy-match the known identifiers in the domain (either variables or functions) and rank them in order of decreasing probability.

---

### Base Definitions

Let's start out by deciding we want our input to be in memory, so we can refer to locations/substrings by using `string_view`s:

```
#include <boost/utility/string_view.hpp>

using Source = boost::string_view;
using Location = Source::const_iterator;
```

### Completion Hints

Besides the AST, we want our parser to generate completion hints (the implicit completion tokens and suggestions)

```
namespace Completion {

    using Candidates = std::vector<std::string>;

    class Hints {
        struct ByLocation {
            template <typename T, typename U>
            bool operator()(T const& a, U const& b) const { return loc(a) < loc(b); }
          private:
            static Location loc(Source const& s) { return s.begin(); }
            static Location loc(Location const& l) { return l; }
        };

      public:
        std::map<Location, std::string, ByLocation> incomplete;
        std::map<Source, Candidates, ByLocation> suggestions;

        /*explicit*/ operator bool() const { return incomplete.size() || suggestions.size(); }
    };
```

In addition, let's code up a quick & dirty fuzzy identifier match scoring function.

I opted for a simple synchronizing compare that

- scores corresponding runs of characters progressively, and
- favours skipping characters from candidates over skipping characters from the input (meaning that `adj_diff` is a good fuzzy match for `adjacent_difference` even though characters have been skipped from the candidate, but `adj_qqq_diff` is worse because the `qqq` from the input could not be matched)
- the algorithm is done recursively and without allocations
- first characters get a boost if matched (`rate=1` at first invocation)

```
    static int fuzzy_match(Source input, boost::string_view candidate, int rate = 1) { // start with first-letter boost
        int score = 0;

        while (!(input.empty() || candidate.empty())) {
            if (input.front() != candidate.front()) {
                return score + std::max(
                    fuzzy_match(input.substr(1), candidate, std::max(rate-2,0)), //penalty for ignoring an input char
                    fuzzy_match(input, candidate.substr(1), std::max(rate-1,0)));
            }

            input.remove_prefix(1);
            candidate.remove_prefix(1);
            score += ++rate;
        }
        return score;
    }

} // namespace Completion
```

We'll see how this is used in the grammar.

### AST

A run-of-the-mill AST that can do binary expressions, string/numeric literals, variables and (nested) function calls:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

namespace Ast {
    using NumLiteral = double;
    using StringLiteral = std::string; // de-escaped, not source view

    struct Identifier : std::string {
        using std::string::string;
        using std::string::operator=;
    };

    struct BinaryExpression;
    struct CallExpression;

    using Expression = boost::variant<
            NumLiteral,
            StringLiteral,
            Identifier,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<BinaryExpression>,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<CallExpression>
        >;

    struct BinaryExpression {
        Expression lhs;
        char op;
        Expression rhs;
    };

    using ArgList = std::vector<Expression>;

    struct CallExpression {
        Identifier function;
        ArgList args;
    };
}
```

### Grammar

---

#### Basics

The grammar starts off pretty "basic" as well:

```
namespace Parsing {
    namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

    template <typename It>
    struct Expression : qi::grammar<It, Ast::Expression()> {
        Expression(Completion::Hints& hints) : Expression::base_type(start), _hints(hints) {
            using namespace qi;

            start      = skip(space) [expression];

            expression = term   [_val = _1] >> *(char_("-+") >> expression) [_val = make_binary(_val, _1, _2)];
            term       = factor [_val = _1] >> *(char_("*/") >> term)       [_val = make_binary(_val, _1, _2)];
            factor     = simple [_val = _1] >> *(char_("^")  >> factor)     [_val = make_binary(_val, _1, _2)];

            simple     = call | variable | compound | number | string;
```

So far so good: The constructor stores a reference to the `Completion::Hints&` to be recorded. All these rules have been declared as `qi::rule<It, Expression(), qi::space_type>`.

#### Implied Tokens

Now it gets slightly more interesting, some rules here are lexemes¹

```
            number     = double_;
            identifier = raw[(alpha|'_') >> *(alnum|'_')];
```

And some productions are tolerant of missing closing tokens:

```
            // imply the closing quotes
            string   %= '"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> implied('"');
            compound %= '(' >> expression >> implied(')');
```

The `implied` magic makes it so that if the expected closing token is missing, it will be recorded as a hint, and parsing continues:

```
            auto implied = [=](char ch) {
                return copy(omit[lit(ch) | raw[eps][imply(_1, ch)]]);
            };
```

Of course, this begs the question what `imply(_1, ch)` really does, and we'll see later.

> For now, observe that we do `raw[eps]` to get an (empty) source `iterator_range` to construct a `Location` from in the semantic action.

#### Identifier Lookup

We store "symbol tables" in `Domain` members `_variables` and `_functions`:

```
        using Domain = qi::symbols<char>;
        Domain _variables, _functions;
```

Then we declare some rules that can do lookups on either of them:

```
        // domain identifier lookups
        qi::_r1_type _domain;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Identifier(Domain const&)> maybe_known, known, unknown;
```

The corresponding declarations will be shown shortly.

Variables are pretty simple:

```
        variable   = maybe_known(phx::ref(_variables));
```

Calls are trickier. If a name is unknown we don't want to assume it implies a *function* unless it's followed by a `'('` character. However, if an identifier is a known function name, we want even to imply the `(` (this gives the UX the appearance of autocompletion where when the user types `sqrt`, it suggests the next character to be `(` magically).

```
        // The heuristics:
        // - an unknown identifier followed by (
        // - an unclosed argument list implies )
        call %= ( known(phx::ref(_functions)) // known -> imply the parens
                     | &(identifier >> '(') >> unknown(phx::ref(_functions))
                     ) >> implied('(') >> -(expression % ',') >> implied(')');
```

It all builds on `known`, `unknown` and `maybe_known`:

```
            ///////////////////////////////
            // identifier loopkup, suggesting
            {
                maybe_known = known(_domain) | unknown(_domain);

                // distinct to avoid partially-matching identifiers
                using boost::spirit::repository::qi::distinct;
                auto kw     = distinct(copy(alnum | '_'));

                known       = raw[kw[lazy(_domain)]];
                unknown     = raw[identifier[_val=_1]] [suggest_for(_1, _domain)];
            }
```

#### Debug, Predefined Variables/Functions

Remaining is a bit of red tape:

```
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (start)
                (expression)(term)(factor)(simple)(compound)
                (call)(variable)
                (identifier)(number)(string)
                //(maybe_known)(known)(unknown) // qi::symbols<> non-streamable
            )

            _variables += "foo", "bar", "qux";
            _functions += "print", "sin", "tan", "sqrt", "frobnicate";
        }

      private:
        Completion::Hints& _hints;

        using Domain = qi::symbols<char>;
        Domain _variables, _functions;

        qi::rule<It, Ast::Expression()> start;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Expression(), qi::space_type> expression, term, factor, simple;
        // completables
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Expression(), qi::space_type> compound;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::CallExpression(), qi::space_type> call;

        // implicit lexemes
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Identifier()> variable, identifier;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::NumLiteral()> number;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::StringLiteral()> string;

        // domain identifier lookups
        qi::_r1_type _domain;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Identifier(Domain const&)> maybe_known, known, unknown;
```

#### Phoenix Helpers

Let's start with the usual helper to construct binary AST nodes:

```
        ///////////////////////////////
        // binary expression factory
        struct make_binary_f {
            Ast::BinaryExpression operator()(Ast::Expression const& lhs, char op, Ast::Expression const& rhs) const {
                return {lhs, op, rhs};
            }
        };
        boost::phoenix::function<make_binary_f> make_binary;
```

Similarly, we can have a Phoenix function object to register implied chars:

```
        ///////////////////////////////
        // auto-completing incomplete expressions
        struct imply_f {
            Completion::Hints& _hints;
            void operator()(boost::iterator_range<It> where, char implied_char) const {
                auto inserted = 
                    _hints.incomplete.emplace(&*where.begin(), std::string(1, implied_char));
                // add the implied char to existing completion
                if (!inserted.second)
                    inserted.first->second += implied_char;
            }
        };
        boost::phoenix::function<imply_f> imply { imply_f { _hints } };
```

Note that it orders by location (which makes UX easier) and detects when a previous implied token lived at the same location, in which case we simply append to it.

By now it won't be much of a surprise that generating relevant suggestions for unknown identifiers is also a phoenix actor:

```
        ///////////////////////////////
        // suggest_for
        struct suggester {
            Completion::Hints& _hints;

            void operator()(boost::iterator_range<It> where, Domain const& symbols) const {
                using namespace Completion;
                Source id(&*where.begin(), where.size());
                Candidates c;

                symbols.for_each([&](std::string const& k, ...) { c.push_back(k); });

                auto score = [id](Source v) { return fuzzy_match(id, v); };
                auto byscore = [=](Source a, Source b) { return score(a) > score(b); };

                sort(c.begin(), c.end(), byscore);
                c.erase( remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), [=](Source s) { return score(s) < 3; }), c.end());

                _hints.suggestions.emplace(id, c);
            }
        };
        boost::phoenix::function<suggester> suggest_for {suggester{_hints}};
```

That's all. If it looks more complicated, that's because it does a lot more: it scores all candidates fuzzily, orders them by descending score and removes any candidates with score < 3.

```
    };
}
```

### BONUS

Let's alter things a little more and allow `','` to be implied inside argument lists:

```
        call %= ( known(phx::ref(_functions)) // known -> imply the parens
                | &(identifier >> '(') >> unknown(phx::ref(_functions))
                ) 
            >> implied('(') 
            >> -(expression % ',')
            >> implied(')')
            ;
```

Let's replace `','` there:

```
            >> -(expression % (',' | !(')'|eoi) >> implied(',')))
```

> **NOTE**: It might seem to make more sense to detect `&expression` to assert that an expression follows, instead asserting that the end of the input/argument list has not been reached.
>
> Doing that goes bad, though, because any contained expressions could trigger more implied tokens as a side effect, leading to duplicated implied tokens.
>
> This (side-effectful semantic actions) is one of the chief reasons why I usually avoid semantic actions, or use them to store effect only in the rule's (exposed) attribute(s). See [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

## TEST DRIVER

This post would be nothing without some nice test cases. So here goes:

```
int main() {
    for (Source const input : {
            "",       // invalid
            "(3",     // incomplete, imply ')'
            "3*(6+sqrt(9))^7 - 1e8", // completely valid
            "(3*(((6+sqrt(9))^7 - 1e8", // incomplete, imply ")))"
            "print(\"hello \\\"world!", // completes the string literal and the parameter list
            "foo",    // okay, known variable
            "baz",    // (suggest bar)
            "baz(",   // incomplete, imply ')', unknown function
            "taz(",   // incomplete, imply ')', unknown function
            "san(",   // 2 suggestions (sin/tan)
            "print(1, 2, \"three\", complicated(san(78",
            "(print sqrt sin 9)    -0) \"bye",
        })
    {
        std::cout << "-------------- '" << input << "'\n";
        Location f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

        Ast::Expression expr;
        Completion::Hints hints;
        bool ok = parse(f, l, Parsing::Expression<Location>{hints}, expr);

        if (hints) {
            std::cout << "Input: '" << input << "'\n";
        }
        for (auto& c : hints.incomplete) {
            std::cout << "Missing " << std::setw(c.first - input.begin()) << "" << "^ implied: '" << c.second << "'\n";
        }
        for (auto& id : hints.suggestions) {
            std::cout << "Unknown " << std::setw(id.first.begin() - input.begin()) << "" << std::string(id.first.size(), '^');
            if (id.second.empty()) 
                std::cout << " (no suggestions)\n";
            else {
                std::cout << " (did you mean ";
                once_t first;
                for (auto& s : id.second)
                    std::cout << (first?"":" or ") << "'" << s << "'";
                std::cout << "?)\n";
            }
        }

        if (ok) {
            std::cout << "AST:    " << expr << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Note that, besides the first input (`""`) everything is heuristically parsed as *some* kind of expression! The last one is designed to show off how all the parameter lists are implied because `print`, `sqrt` and `sin` are known functions. Then some `','` are implied, before finally the unclosed string literal and remaining parentheses are closed. Here's the (non-debug) output:

```
-------------- ''
Parse failed
-------------- '(3'
Input: '(3'
Missing   ^ implied: ')'
AST:    3
-------------- '3*(6+sqrt(9))^7 - 1e8'
AST:    ((3 * ((6 + (sqrt (9))) ^ 7)) - 1e+08)
-------------- '(3*(((6+sqrt(9))^7 - 1e8'
Input: '(3*(((6+sqrt(9))^7 - 1e8'
Missing                         ^ implied: ')))'
AST:    (3 * (((6 + (sqrt (9))) ^ 7) - 1e+08))
-------------- 'print("hello \"world!'
Input: 'print("hello \"world!'
Missing                      ^ implied: '")'
AST:    (print (hello "world!))
-------------- 'foo'
AST:    foo
-------------- 'baz'
Input: 'baz'
Unknown ^^^ (did you mean 'bar'?)
AST:    baz
-------------- 'baz('
Input: 'baz('
Missing     ^ implied: ')'
Unknown ^^^ (no suggestions)
AST:    (baz ())
-------------- 'taz('
Input: 'taz('
Missing     ^ implied: ')'
Unknown ^^^ (did you mean 'tan'?)
AST:    (taz ())
-------------- 'san('
Input: 'san('
Missing     ^ implied: ')'
Unknown ^^^ (did you mean 'sin' or 'tan'?)
AST:    (san ())
-------------- 'print(1, 2, "three", complicated(san(78'
Input: 'print(1, 2, "three", complicated(san(78'
Missing                                        ^ implied: ')))'
Unknown                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ (did you mean 'frobnicate' or 'print'?)
Unknown                                  ^^^ (did you mean 'sin' or 'tan'?)
AST:    (print (1, 2, three, (complicated ((san (78))))))
-------------- '(print sqrt sin 9)    -0) "bye'
Input: '(print sqrt sin 9)    -0) "bye'
Missing        ^ implied: '('
Missing             ^ implied: '('
Missing                 ^ implied: '('
Missing                           ^ implied: ','
Missing                               ^ implied: '"))'
AST:    (print ((sqrt (((sin (9)) - 0))), bye))
```

## Full Listing / Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1b0c5c573e9ec78)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/utility/string_view.hpp>

using Source = boost::string_view;
using Location = Source::const_iterator;

#include <map>
#include <vector>

namespace Completion {

    static int fuzzy_match(Source input, boost::string_view candidate, int rate = 1) { // start with first-letter boost
        int score = 0;

        while (!(input.empty() || candidate.empty())) {
            if (input.front() != candidate.front()) {
                return score + std::max(
                    fuzzy_match(input.substr(1), candidate, std::max(rate-2,0)), //penalty for ignoring an input char
                    fuzzy_match(input, candidate.substr(1), std::max(rate-1,0)));
            }

            input.remove_prefix(1);
            candidate.remove_prefix(1);
            score += ++rate;
        }
        return score;
    }

    using Candidates = std::vector<std::string>;

    class Hints {
        struct ByLocation {
            template <typename T, typename U>
            bool operator()(T const& a, U const& b) const { return loc(a) < loc(b); }
          private:
            static Location loc(Source const& s) { return s.begin(); }
            static Location loc(Location const& l) { return l; }
        };

      public:
        std::map<Location, std::string, ByLocation> incomplete;
        std::map<Source, Candidates, ByLocation> suggestions;

        /*explicit*/ operator bool() const { return incomplete.size() || suggestions.size(); }
    };
}

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

namespace Ast {
    using NumLiteral = double;
    using StringLiteral = std::string; // de-escaped, not source view

    struct Identifier : std::string {
        using std::string::string;
        using std::string::operator=;
    };

    struct BinaryExpression;
    struct CallExpression;

    using Expression = boost::variant<
            NumLiteral,
            StringLiteral,
            Identifier,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<BinaryExpression>,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<CallExpression>
        >;

    struct BinaryExpression {
        Expression lhs;
        char op;
        Expression rhs;
    };

    using ArgList = std::vector<Expression>;

    struct CallExpression {
        Identifier function;
        ArgList args;
    };
}

#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::BinaryExpression, lhs, op, rhs)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::CallExpression, function, args)

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_distinct.hpp>

// for debug printing:
namespace {
    struct once_t { // an auto-reset flag
        operator bool() { bool v = flag; flag = false; return v; }
        bool flag = true;
    };
}

// for debug printing:
namespace Ast {

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<Expression> const& args) {
        os << "(";
        once_t first;
        for (auto& a : args) os << (first?"":", ") << a;
        return os << ")";
    }

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, BinaryExpression const& e) {
        return os << boost::fusion::as_vector(e);
    }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, CallExpression const& e) {
        return os << boost::fusion::as_vector(e);
    }
}

namespace Parsing {
    namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

    template <typename It>
    struct Expression : qi::grammar<It, Ast::Expression()> {
        Expression(Completion::Hints& hints) : Expression::base_type(start), _hints(hints) {
            using namespace qi;

            start      = skip(space) [expression];

            expression = term   [_val = _1] >> *(char_("-+") >> expression) [_val = make_binary(_val, _1, _2)];
            term       = factor [_val = _1] >> *(char_("*/") >> term)       [_val = make_binary(_val, _1, _2)];
            factor     = simple [_val = _1] >> *(char_("^")  >> factor)     [_val = make_binary(_val, _1, _2)];

            simple     = call | variable | compound | number | string;

            auto implied = [=](char ch) {
                return copy(omit[lit(ch) | raw[eps][imply(_1, ch)]]);
            };

            variable   = maybe_known(phx::ref(_variables));

            compound  %= '(' >> expression >> implied(')');

            // The heuristics:
            // - an unknown identifier followed by (
            // - an unclosed argument list implies )
            call %= ( known(phx::ref(_functions)) // known -> imply the parens
                    | &(identifier >> '(') >> unknown(phx::ref(_functions))
                    ) 
                >> implied('(') 
                >> -(expression % (',' | !(')'|eoi) >> implied(',')))
                >> implied(')')
                ;

            // lexemes, primitive rules
            identifier  = raw[(alpha|'_') >> *(alnum|'_')];

            // imply the closing quotes
            string     %= '"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> implied('"'); // TODO more escapes

            number      = double_; // TODO integral arguments

            ///////////////////////////////
            // identifier loopkup, suggesting
            {
                maybe_known = known(_domain) | unknown(_domain);

                // distinct to avoid partially-matching identifiers
                using boost::spirit::repository::qi::distinct;
                auto kw     = distinct(copy(alnum | '_'));

                known       = raw[kw[lazy(_domain)]];
                unknown     = raw[identifier[_val=_1]] [suggest_for(_1, _domain)];
            }

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (start)
                (expression)(term)(factor)(simple)(compound)
                (call)(variable)
                (identifier)(number)(string)
                //(maybe_known)(known)(unknown) // qi::symbols<> non-streamable
            )

            _variables += "foo", "bar", "qux";
            _functions += "print", "sin", "tan", "sqrt", "frobnicate";
        }

      private:
        Completion::Hints& _hints;

        using Domain = qi::symbols<char>;
        Domain _variables, _functions;

        qi::rule<It, Ast::Expression()> start;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Expression(), qi::space_type> expression, term, factor, simple;
        // completables
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Expression(), qi::space_type> compound;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::CallExpression(), qi::space_type> call;

        // implicit lexemes
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Identifier()> variable, identifier;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::NumLiteral()> number;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::StringLiteral()> string;

        // domain identifier lookups
        qi::_r1_type _domain;
        qi::rule<It, Ast::Identifier(Domain const&)> maybe_known, known, unknown;

        ///////////////////////////////
        // binary expression factory
        struct make_binary_f {
            Ast::BinaryExpression operator()(Ast::Expression const& lhs, char op, Ast::Expression const& rhs) const {
                return {lhs, op, rhs};
            }
        };
        boost::phoenix::function<make_binary_f> make_binary;

        ///////////////////////////////
        // auto-completing incomplete expressions
        struct imply_f {
            Completion::Hints& _hints;
            void operator()(boost::iterator_range<It> where, char implied_char) const {
                auto inserted = 
                    _hints.incomplete.emplace(&*where.begin(), std::string(1, implied_char));
                // add the implied char to existing completion
                if (!inserted.second)
                    inserted.first->second += implied_char;
            }
        };
        boost::phoenix::function<imply_f> imply { imply_f { _hints } };

        ///////////////////////////////
        // suggest_for
        struct suggester {
            Completion::Hints& _hints;

            void operator()(boost::iterator_range<It> where, Domain const& symbols) const {
                using namespace Completion;
                Source id(&*where.begin(), where.size());
                Candidates c;

                symbols.for_each([&](std::string const& k, ...) { c.push_back(k); });

                auto score = [id](Source v) { return fuzzy_match(id, v); };
                auto byscore = [=](Source a, Source b) { return score(a) > score(b); };

                sort(c.begin(), c.end(), byscore);
                c.erase( remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), [=](Source s) { return score(s) < 3; }), c.end());

                _hints.suggestions.emplace(id, c);
            }
        };
        boost::phoenix::function<suggester> suggest_for {suggester{_hints}};

    };
}

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    for (Source const input : {
            "",       // invalid
            "(3",     // incomplete, imply ')'
            "3*(6+sqrt(9))^7 - 1e8", // completely valid
            "(3*(((6+sqrt(9))^7 - 1e8", // incomplete, imply ")))"
            "print(\"hello \\\"world!", // completes the string literal and the parameter list
            "foo",    // okay, known variable
            "baz",    // (suggest bar)
            "baz(",   // incomplete, imply ')', unknown function
            "taz(",   // incomplete, imply ')', unknown function
            "san(",   // 2 suggestions (sin/tan)
            "print(1, 2, \"three\", complicated(san(78",
            "(print sqrt sin 9)    -0) \"bye",
        })
    {
        std::cout << "-------------- '" << input << "'\n";
        Location f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

        Ast::Expression expr;
        Completion::Hints hints;
        bool ok = parse(f, l, Parsing::Expression<Location>{hints}, expr);

        if (hints) {
            std::cout << "Input: '" << input << "'\n";
        }
        for (auto& c : hints.incomplete) {
            std::cout << "Missing " << std::setw(c.first - input.begin()) << "" << "^ implied: '" << c.second << "'\n";
        }
        for (auto& id : hints.suggestions) {
            std::cout << "Unknown " << std::setw(id.first.begin() - input.begin()) << "" << std::string(id.first.size(), '^');
            if (id.second.empty()) 
                std::cout << " (no suggestions)\n";
            else {
                std::cout << " (did you mean ";
                once_t first;
                for (auto& s : id.second)
                    std::cout << (first?"":" or ") << "'" << s << "'";
                std::cout << "?)\n";
            }
        }

        if (ok) {
            std::cout << "AST:    " << expr << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

---

¹ [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)

Comment: Related to that "NOTE" about side-effectful semantic actions, here's the fully attribute-based version that I initially had: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fa23f1df1e25c63)**. Note how it encodes incomplete (sub) expressions/suggested identifiers right inside the AST. Not also that it didn't allow me to hint at missing `'('` or `','` because they occur in the middle of expressions. This is what made me switch the approach.

Comment: Woah, amazing work @sehe! That was exactly what I wanted to achieve!

Comment: @PiotrK I figured that. It does fall squarely into the "just code it yourself" category, of course, though having a bit of Spirit experience helps a lot (each of `eps`, `raw`, `kw`, `_r1` and `lazy` could be viewed as "advanced Spirit" on their own). I just wanted to try it for myself too. I predict that you will run into question when adapting to your own use case (how to lookup members for `foo.member` expressions? How to handle expressions returning functions, little shifts in grammar rules could break automatic attribute propagation etc). Feel free to ask if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Spirit doesn't have that feature. You could generate it yourself but it would be considerable effort to do it generically (if not straight up impossible, due  NP-completeness). Perhaps just detect parse error (`on_error`) and have a limited number of stock "options" - the 80% rule should go a long way.

Also, I think the "sketch" with parsing 'invalid placeholder tokens'  will not work because you'll have to build in assumptions about the type of the placeholder token and it may therefore not result in a valid expression.

I sense that you treat expression parsing as little more than tokenizing -
 which isn't accurate in most cases.

Comment: Well, MS Intellisense also is getting lost on invalid code, 20% cases is still up there ;-) But I wonder how Intellisense works when applying to code that is just being typed...

Comment: I [couldn't leave well enough alone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47383910/85371)...